# hdiapi how to access device in user mode?

Tags: libusb, udev, hidapi

I am running [the test script from GitHub](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/tree/master/hidtest), and I can only open the device as root.

While calling `hid_enumerate(0x0, 0x0)`, it works in user mode.

My udev rule looks like this:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTR{idProduct}=="e008",
>   MODE="0666"

The rule is working because I can run `he2325u_pyusb` in user mode.
Disabling this rule, the script runs only with root rights.

How can I access the device in user mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I could fix the problem
I changed the udev rules like this:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e008",
>   MODE="0666" KERNEL=="hidraw*",ATTRS{busnum}=="2", 
>   ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e008", MODE="0666",
>   GROUP="users"

The very important thing was to append a `*` at the end of the KERNEL parameter `hidraw*`.